# How do you change the amount of time before the screen dims?

Tags: 13.10, screen

As a video watcher, I get rather agitated when my screen dims and then turns off while I am watching something. I do not want to be interrupted every 10 minutes or so and have to move the mouse. I want to make it a more convenient amount of time like an hour or so. How would I go about doing this.

Windows user, Linux lover.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

click on the battery icon on the top-panel and then select power settings,after that select screen brightness option.

[image]

- Untick the *Dim screen to save power* option.
- Select the dropdown-list and change to 1 hour in  "*Turn screen off when inactive for*" option.