# How to enlarge the dimming time of the screen saver

Tags: 12.04, screensaver

Before switching off the screen, the screen saver dims the screen a bit. For me, the time of having the screen dimmed is not long enough, so I often have to retype my password. I'd like to have a longer dim-time. How can I get this?

(I am not asking for [How do you change the amount of time before the screen dims?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/390138/how-do-you-change-the-amount-of-time-before-the-screen-dims))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems this value (10 seconds) is hard coded in the code. There is no way to change it unless you re-compile the power management code. It's managed by `gnome-screensaver`.

[image]

Source: http://people.canonical.com/~bradf/power-management.html

You can however download gnome-screensaver source package from Launchpad: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/+source/gnome-screensaver. The source code of fade out effect can be found in `gs-fade.c` and `gs-fade.h` files from `src` directory:

[image]

To install, follow this post: [Installing applications from source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/123077/installing-applications-from-source)

Credit to: [Gnome source code of fade out effect for inactivity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313486/gnome-source-code-of-fade-out-effect-for-inactivity)