# How to change Spread all windows animation speed?

Tags: unity, compiz

I know using CCSM I can change the animation speeds of minimize window, open window, etc. But I can't find the section that lets me modify the animation speeds of 'spread all windows' (Super + W shortcut) and can't find the option to change the fade to desktop speed. Anyone know where to find it?

Comment: For the fade to desktop speed, I think [this question](http://www.askubuntu.com/questions/437833/how-to-enlarge-the-dimming-time-of-the-screen-saver) can be of some interest.

Comment: I doubt you can change it..

Comment: so it's hard wired into the system? I don't really understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install CompizConfig Settings Manager from Ubuntu Software Manager.
In Animations area you should be able to change the speed.